# NoMethodError in Home#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Everything was working fine until yesterday , today i opened the app and it greeted me with the above mentioned error .

Following is the part where the error is getting shown

```
app/views/devise/registrations/_errors.html.slim where line #5 raised:

undefined method `each' for "Signed in successfully.":String

Extracted source (around line #5):

- if flash[:error]
h4 Error messages
ul
- flash[:error].each do |error|
li= error
- if flash[:error_validate_card]
= flash[:error_validate_card]
```

## Update - application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :save_controller
  after_filter :store_location


  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:error] = "Access denied."
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

## Update2 - Session controller

```
class Devise::SessionsController < DeviseController

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    if valid_email?(params[:user][:email] , params[:user][:password]) || params[:user][:password].blank?
       flash[:error] = "Email or password is incorrect"
       redirect_to :back
    else
       self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
       set_flash_message(:error, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
       sign_in(resource_name, resource)
       respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    end
  end
```

## Update3

Views -> Devise -> Registerations -> file

```
  <%= form_for(CreativeRequestUser.new,:url=>app_creative_requests_path(),:html=>{:method=>:post,:id=>"creative_request_form"}) do|f| %>
```

Also i recently removed rails_admin from my app , but it was working fine even after that .

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated , thanks in advance :)

Comment: flash[:error] showing as a string. And the success message is assigned in flash[:error] . Can you show the controller code ?

Comment: "Signed in successfully.":String is your flash string not array, string can not have each method used with it.

Comment: check your flash[:error]

Comment: did the update , please check .

Comment: have you editted devise registrations controller create action? If then show ..

Comment: done , can you see and tell what is wrong here .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually i found the error was due to bundle update command i had fired , had to re-install the older versions of all gems .

Note to self and all the future users - Use bundle update very carefully .

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to itterate through errors in flash[:error], but you assigned string to `flash[:error]`.
You usually use `flash[:error] = @item.errors.full_messages` to get array of messages, but in your case to hotfix your code you just need to write like that

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  flash[:error] << "Access denied." # see I add you message into flash[:error] array
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Same staff to Session controller
`flash[:error] << "Email or password is incorrect"`

Comment: when error is going to be a fed message why should we use array? He should change code in view itself.

Comment: Tried it but isn't helping

Comment: @AlokAnand - i had changed the registeration view part too ,should i post it ?

Comment: @CaffeineCoder see what is happening, flash[:error] = "String", and in view you are doing flash[:error].each, you are trying to iterate over a string value, it is not correct, so in view you do not do flash[:error].each, just do use = flash[:error]

Answer (score 0):

Please update the session controller like

```
# POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    if valid_email?(params[:user][:email] , params[:user][:password]) || params[:user][:password].blank?
       flash[:error] = "Email or password is incorrect"
       redirect_to :back
    else
       self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
       set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
       sign_in(resource_name, resource)
       respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    end
  end
```

Error in assigning :error rather to :notice 
error in line set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?

Comment: Did you change like this set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?